# Laravel not redirecting (but HTML response seen in Network tab)

Tags: laravel

I have a fairly straightforward requirements: From one of the controller functions, I need to redirect the page to a named route and pass along some data.

What I tried the source controller function was this:

```
    // . . .
    $patent->save();
    return redirect()->route('patents.update', [$patent]);
}
```

The named route `patents.update` is defined in my `routes/web.php` as:

```
Route::get('patents/update', 'PatentsController@update')->name('patents.update');
```

And finally, the destination controller function:

```
public function update(Patent $patent) {
    return view('patents.update');
}
```

The problem is that when I run this, the page stays where it is, while the view I'm looking for is received as GET response in the Network tab in Chrome. Why's the redirect not working?

Answer (score 0):

your route doesnt have a parameter for the patent id? Seems a little odd since you are trying to fetch a $patent from method injection

Another note, if you are looking to use restful routes, it should be edit and not update. the update route should make a patch request to update the model.

Comment: Hmmm. Please suggest how to add. :-)

Comment: you need `Route::get('patents/{id}/edit' ...` or something like that

Comment: No, it's not REST at all. Just some soup I need to work with.

Comment: either way, you still need something to tell laravel which 'patent' you are editing. /patents/update doesnt give the application any hint as to which patent you want.

Comment: Well, this seems quite intricate to me and I'm short on time. So I'm using a JavaScript redirect for now. Thanks for your answer. :-)